# python tkinter passing variables between functions

Tags: python, compiler-errors, tkinter, instance-variables

I am trying to pass the variable dirpath into the export_data() function. Export data runs off of a double click on a button located on a widget. Why is dirpath printing as:

```
`<Tkinter.Event instance at 0x8ade56c>`
```

instead of the actual path?

```
def export_data(dirpath):
    print 'exporting...'
    print str(dirpath)
    os.mkdir('/home/bigl/Desktop/Library')
    shutil.copytree(dirpath, output_path)
```

When I run my code I get the error

```
exporting...
<Tkinter.Event instance at 0x8ade56c>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/media/LOFTUS/20130308_searchtest.py", line 44, in export_data
    shutil.copytree(dirpath, output_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 169, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

Comment: Can you maybe figure out what you're having a problem with, and ask a question about that? Your story is a bit all over the map.

Comment: PS. I don't know why you think `dirpath` is a global variable; it's the argument of your `export_data()` function, hence local.

Comment: perhaps that is clearer?

Comment: Much better! It is now possible to guess at the problem.

Comment: Are you being sarcastic or what? What else should I provide if you need more. There is a lot of code and I do not think it is relevant to show it all. I am making sure that dirpath is returned and I thought that this was enough to go by

Comment: Not at all! See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of the question you asked:

> Export data runs off of a double click on a button located on a
>   widget. Why is dirpath printing as:
>
> `<Tkinter.Event instance at 0x8ade56c>`

When you bind to an event, the binding always sends an event object as a parameter to the bound function. So, if you're doing:

```
widget.bind("<Double-1>", export_data)
```

... then `export_data` will receive the event as it's only parameter.

To pass a variable, you need to use `lambda` or `functools.partial` or some sort of function generator. For example:

```
widget.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event: export_data(dirpath))
```

Be careful with this, however. The value passed to `export_data` will be the value of `dirpath` *at the time the event occurs*, which may be different than the value when you creating the binding.

If you have a local variable that you want to pass to the function you can set it as a default value to a keyword argument, in which case the value at the time the `lambda` is created will be passed.

Example:

```
path = some_function()
widget.bind("<Double-1>", lamba event, dirpath=path: export_data(dirpath))
```

Comment: Yes, this is the better solution. Avoid globals in your functions wherever possible-- pass `output_path` as an argument too.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `Tkinter` passes an event, not a string, to your callback. If `dirpath` is a global variable (as you wrote before-- important information!), perhaps you meant to define your callback like this:

```
def export_data(_ignored):
    print 'exporting...'
    print str(dirpath)
    os.mkdir('/home/bigl/Desktop/Library')
    shutil.copytree(dirpath, output_path)
```

Now your function can use the global `dirpath` (and `output_path`). The way you had it, the argument declaration was hiding the global of the same name.

Comment: this works great. I will try to make my questions clearer next time thank you